# How can you determine Mass / kg from the attached table

Tags: mathematical-physics

[image]

I spent the last two hours trying to figure out part D and I can't get my head around it... Part D has the formula mass/kg = Mass/kg = C / ΣC 
I'd imagine "C" is the number of C section of the table.
Does anyone know how can I calculate that number?

Comment: $D$ seems to be the fraction of total mass, e.g. $5.28 / 29.92 \approx 0.176$ (which means $17.6\%$ of the total mass)

Answer (score 1):

Take that C and divide it with the sum of all Cs.
For D1 just divide 5.28 with 29.92.
//29.92 is sum of all Cs, 29.92=5.28+0.84+23.8

Answer (score 1):

You take the value of C from that row and divide it from the sum provided at the bottom of column C. For example:

for CO2: take $\dfrac{5.28(\text{Mass of CO2})}{29.92}$ = .17647

for CO: take $\dfrac{.84(\text{Mass of CO})}{29.92}$ = 0.02807, etc.

If there was confusion about what was in the denominator, $\Sigma C$ means the sum of elements in column C. Where in this case $\Sigma C = 5.28+.84+23.8$ = 29.92